# Converting text using Base64 in Linux and Windows

Tags: windows, linux, encryption

I need to *encrypt* text/files in base 64 so I can send them in an email (I can't do attachments). I can use openSSL and GPG in Linux to encrypt and decrypt but don't know how to do the same in Windows XP. Does anyone know a program that can do this for me in windows?

Comment: You do realize base64 isn't encryption, yes?

Comment: To complete what @Brian Roach is telling you: base64 is a way to store your strings in a "transmittable" way, but they are plain text (not encrypted). For encryption you could use AES, 3DES, etc...

Comment: I'm assuming anyone who has grabbed the keywords gpg, openssl will have realized that base64 is only the content encoding

Comment: @sehe - that's a bold assumption here. You wouldn't need either for base64

Comment: Why would a person go the lengths to use **both** `openssl` **and** `gpg` on linux, if it was only to do what `base64` can do on it's own? It's basic laws of entropy, and I'm rating the chance of someone accidentally falling into both ssl and gpg when googling for base64 pretty low.

Comment: base 64 is how you output the encrypted data.

Comment: @sehe - I don't use both, what I'm saying is i have both and can use them. i usually just use openSSL.

Comment: @sehe - Because ... people are really, really bad at this stuff. You've answered over 500 questions here, I'm surprised at your optimism ;)

Comment: @Brian: it's the other way around; without the optimism, I would have never reached 500 answers in the first place. I agree in the general sense: people are bad at security stuff. @antonvrg: thanks for confirming. Perhaps just see [here](http://wolfram.org/writing/howto/gpg.html) or.... [here](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=gpg+windows&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)?

Comment: Touche. I'm just a realist; I do what I can. Though ... in the end, maybe that makes me an optimist after all.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED AGAIN**
In this [link](http://snipplr.com/view/6034/base64-encode-or-decode-a-file/) you can find how to encode/decode files.
I attach sample code:

```
private string FileToBase64(string srcFilename)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(srcFilename))
  {
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(srcFilename, 
                                   FileMode.Open, 
                                   FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(filebytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes,
        Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
    return encodedData; 
  }
}

private void Base64ToFile(string src, string dstFilename)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dstFilename))
  {
    byte[] filebytes = Convert.FromBase64String(src);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(dstFilename, 
                                   FileMode.CreateNew, 
                                   FileAccess.Write, 
                                   FileShare.None);
    fs.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length);
    fs.Close(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: @antonvrg: base64 encoding and decoding is built-in in C#: add two implemented methods as you see in examples and your job is done. Why do you need something already compiled?

Comment: because I can't compile software and it would be easier to just get the files, not the source.

Comment: @antonvrg: I don't understand.. are you writing an app to accomplish your task or not? You can use Visual Studio Express Edition (which is completely free) to compile this small app. Excuse me, but I can't see what's your problem..

Comment: @antonvrg: look at my edited post. There's a new link for you. I hope this helps :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24727875)

Comment: @deepseefan: I changed my answer attaching sample code